# How do I solve Connection problem using TAD class php

Tags: php, zkteco

I'm using TAD class php for connection to a attendance machine but I tried so many solutions and codes but I failed can any one help me please.

This is for my attendance management system using php codeigniter now I am using a manual method for getting attendance from machine to MySql. Everyday early morning i download all the attendance from the machine using Software which was provided by the machine company and then the software download all the attendance logs into a MS Access db file and then i read the attendance from this file.But now I want a direct connection to machine.
Here is some code that i tried using TAD class but as always i got a connection error.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'lib/TADFactory.php';
require 'lib/TAD.php';
require 'lib/TADResponse.php';
require 'lib/Providers/TADSoap.php';
require 'lib/Providers/TADZKLib.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/ConnectionError.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/FilterArgumentError.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/UnrecognizedArgument.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/UnrecognizedCommand.php';

use TADPHP\TADFactory;
use TADPHP\TAD;


try {
        $tad = (new TADFactory(['ip' =>
        '192.168.2.200','com_key'=>0]))->get_instance();
        if($tad->is_alive())
        {
                    echo "done";exit();
                    //$tad->disable();
                    $att_logs = $tad->get_att_log();
                    // print_r($att_logs);exit();
                    $att_logs=$att_logs->filter_by_date(['start' => date('Y-m-d'),'end' =>
                    date('Y-m-d')]);
                    if ($att_logs->is_empty_response())
                    {
                        my_log('Does not have logs recorded');
                    //continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $array_att_logs = $att_logs->to_array();
                        $device_logs = array();
                        $counter=1;
                        if(!empty($array_att_logs))
                            foreach($array_att_logs as $key =>$val )
                            {
                                foreach($val as $log)
                                {
                                    $device_logs[]= array(
                                    'institutes_inst_id' => $row['inst_id'],
                                    'employees_machine_user_id' => $log['PIN'],
                                    'date' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($log['DateTime'])),
                                    'time' => date('H:i:s',strtotime($log['DateTime']))
                                    );
                                    $counter++;
                                }
                            }
                        add_att_logs($device_logs);
                        //$tad->enable();
                        my_log('Device in ' . $row['inst_name']. '['.$row['ip_address']. '] has ' .
                        $counter . ' records');
                    }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "not";exit();
                    my_log('Device in ' . $row['inst_name'] . ' is off-line');
                    continue;
        }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        my_log('Device in ' . $row['inst_name']. '['.$row['ip_address']. '] is
        offline');
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "Access Control Software" get the 'ip' and 'comm_key' for the device. Maybe your ip and comm_key that you are providing here
`$tad = (new TADFactory(['ip' =>'192.168.2.200','com_key'=>0]))->get_instance();` is wrong.

Also you need to enable php_sockets.dll and php_soap.dll in your php.ini file.

Comment: What is com_key and where can i find this key ?

Comment: php_socket and php_soap both are enabled and ip address is 100% correct but I don't know com_key.

Comment: @Haseebkhan Go to device's Main Menu -> Comm. -> PC Connection . You will find the comm key. By default its empty i think so you can try this and see if it works or not. `$tad = (new TADFactory(['ip' =>'192.168.2.200','com_key'=>'']))->get_instance();`

Comment: Thanks alot my device is connected but only return users information only other functions not working (like getAttendance() & getSizeUser() etc ) only getUser() are working.

Comment: Yeah i have also just started working on it it's a bit complex. I am having trouble working with TADResponse. And also there is not much help available on internet.

Comment: When you find any solution then please post your answer here and Thank you so much for help

Comment: You should look at the "README.md" file provided with the cobisja/tad-php api it will help you.